# getJobStatus error in Hadoop

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying run an example program from Hadoop in Action Book. The example is 4-1. This is just a simple MR program to give a comma separated key and value pairs.

I am getting an error with JobClient.runJob() method. I am not sure where I made mistakes, it is just what's given in book. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner;

public class MyJob extends Configured implements Tool {

public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
        implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void map(Text key, Text value,
                    OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        output.collect(value, key);
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase
        implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                       OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                       Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        String csv = "";
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            if (csv.length() > 0) csv += ",";
            csv += values.next().toString();
        }
        output.collect(key, new Text(csv));
    }
}

public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();

    JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, MyJob.class);

    Path in = new Path(args[0]);
    Path out = new Path(args[1]);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

    job.setJobName("MyJob");
    job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");

    JobClient.runJob(job);

    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyJob(), args);

    System.exit(res);
}
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/LocalJobRunner, method: getJobStatus signature: (Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobStatus;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1411)
    at MyJob.run(MyJob.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at MyJob.main(MyJob.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue here. Just to leave a note, the problem is that both mr1 and yarn jars are present in classpath and the classes are getting mixed together.